# how to stop EC2 charges for provisioned storage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

every month I am getting billed $0.11 for this `$0.114 per GB-month of General Purpose SSD (gp2) provisioned storage - Asia Pacific`

I checked the EC2 dashboard and 'Instances', 'AMIs', 'Volumes' and 'Snapshots' are all empty. I literally cannot find this attached storage anywhere.

Comment: Can you provide more details, such as a screenshot? For example, which Region does it say? Did you check the `Volumes` tab for that Region?

Answer (score 0):

Check also other services using EBS under the hood. For example AWS RDS.